# concat variables in new lines with TCL

Tags: tcl, concatenation, newline, string-concatenation

I'd like to concat some string-based variables and I want each of them in a new line. However, I can't find the correct way to write the code. This is what I tried:

```
set mensaje "Error: esta atenuacion: $att dB\n"

gset listaMensajes  [concat [gget listaMensajes] "$mensaje"]

set mensaje "Error: esta atenuacion: $att dB\n"

gset listaMensajes  [concat [gget listaMensajes] "$mensaje"]

puts "[gget listaMensajes]"
```

The variable $att takes different values in the different parts of the code.

I also tried:

```
gset listaMensajes  [concat [gget listaMensajes] "\n" "$mensaje"]
```

but none of them work; I get the messages in the same line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `concat` command strips whitespace between its arguments, so it isn't much use here. What you probably want is the `join` command. Since you are using non-standard commands, I can't recreate your case, but say that `foo` is a command that returns a list of strings:

```
join [foo] \n
```

returns a string consisting of the strings returned by `foo`, with a newline chaaracter joining each string pair.

This of course also works if you have a list of strings in a variable called `bar`:

```
join $bar \n
```

Or if you build a list in a command substitution:

```
join [list "foo bar" "baz qux"] \n
```

Documentation:
[concat](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/concat.htm),
[join](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/join.htm)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked! In my example would be gset listaMensajes [join [list "[gget listaMensajes]" "$mensaje"] \n]